# Only one occurence of the symbol in string - regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

I have a string like that:

```
var x = _something_ somethingelse _whatever_
```

I'd like to match by regular expressions only *something* and *whatever* words (because they are located between two underscore characters directly). Rest word is between underscore characters by accident - I don't need it.
The regular expression I use is matches all of them. How to fixed that? My curent regexp:

```
/_(.*)_/gm
```

Comment: You may use: `/_([^_]+)_/g`

Answer (score 0):

You could search for a word boundary and then for underscore.

```js
var x = '_something_ somethingelse _whatever_ foo_bar _foo_2';

console.log(x.match(/\b_[^_]+_\b/g));
```